# Duplicate column name in count joins

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try to obtain the amount of joins in this query, I get an `#1060 - Duplicate column name 'columnXY'`, because there is a column with this name in both tables. How can I avoid this? I don't see why it should this make it impossible  to count the joins.

```
SELECT count(*) as c
FROM
(SELECT *
 FROM table1
 join table2 on table1.index = table2.index)  T1
```

Comment: The * in the select statement selects two columns with the same name, one from each table.  Also, isn't this the total number of records in the query result, not the number of joins in the query?

Answer (score 2):

Why not shorten to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.index = table2.index
```

Here the column names should not matter at all.